# extracting object from array of array using es6

Tags: javascript

how can i return an array of objects taking from array of again  one more level array. I am using push.

is there any better way to achieve this

```js
let a = [{b: [{c: "k"}]}]

let o = []

a.forEach(so => {so.b.forEach(obc => o.push(obc))})

console.log(o)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead:

```js
const a = [{
    b: [{
      foo: 'foo'
    }]
  },
  {
    b: [{
        c: "k"
      },
      {
        bar: 'bar'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const o = a.flatMap(({ b }) => b);
console.log(o);
```

(but this is a relatively new method, so if you want to use it and still support older environments, be sure to include a polyfill)

Lacking that, you can also improve your existing code by using [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with the inner array instead of iterating over each inner item:

```js
const a = [{
    b: [{
      foo: 'foo'
    }]
  },
  {
    b: [{
        c: "k"
      },
      {
        bar: 'bar'
      }
    ]
  }
];

let o = [];
a.forEach(({ b }) => {
  o = o.concat(b);
});
console.log(o);
```

Comment: without using polyfill anyother methods or its better to use array.push

Answer (score -1):

Try

```js
let a = [{b: [{c: "k"}]}]

let o =a[0].b
console.log(o)
```

Comment: i don't want to statically code as 0 as index. I have given a snippet to understand the question

Comment: you can add param with  index you want